# How apply a function to list of SpatRaster using terra

Tags: r, raster, terra

I have a list of raster files that I can read with `terra`. I would like to apply simple mathematical functions that result in one `SpatRaster` with similar dimensions to the input. The functions (i.e. from `terra`) `median`, `max`, and `min` don't work, while `mean` and `stdev` works perfectly. Here is a minimal example:

```
library(terra)
f <- rast(system.file("ex/elev.tif", package="terra"))
f1<-c(f,f);f2<-c(f,f) # I'm doing this because actual rasters has multiple layers. 

rlist<-list(c(f,f),f1,f2)

# calculate different ensemble statistics
KMean <- Reduce(terra::mean, rlist)
KMedian <- Reduce(terra::median, rlist)
Ksd <- Reduce(terra::stdev, rlist)

KMax <- Reduce(terra::max, rlist)
KMin <- Reduce(terra::min, rlist)
```

Here are the error that I get from running `median`, `max`, and `min`:

```
> rlist
[[1]]
class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 90, 95, 2  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 0.008333333, 0.008333333  (x, y)
extent      : 5.741667, 6.533333, 49.44167, 50.19167  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 (EPSG:4326) 
sources     : elev.tif  
              elev.tif  
names       : elevation, elevation 
min values  :       141,       141 
max values  :       547,       547 

[[2]]
class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 90, 95, 2  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 0.008333333, 0.008333333  (x, y)
extent      : 5.741667, 6.533333, 49.44167, 50.19167  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 (EPSG:4326) 
sources     : elev.tif  
              elev.tif  
names       : elevation, elevation 
min values  :       141,       141 
max values  :       547,       547 

[[3]]
class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 90, 95, 2  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 0.008333333, 0.008333333  (x, y)
extent      : 5.741667, 6.533333, 49.44167, 50.19167  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 (EPSG:4326) 
sources     : elev.tif  
              elev.tif  
names       : elevation, elevation 
min values  :       141,       141 
max values  :       547,       547 

> KMedian <- Reduce(terra::median, rlist)
Error: [median] na.rm (the second argument) must be a logical value
> KMax <- Reduce(terra::max, rlist)
Error: 'max' is not an exported object from 'namespace:terra'
> KMin <- Reduce(terra::min, rlist)
Error: 'min' is not an exported object from 'namespace:terra'
```

Notes:

- All raster have the same dimensions.

Here are the session info:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.2.1 (2022-06-23)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openblas-pthread/libblas.so.3
LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openblas-pthread/liblapack.so.3

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_GB.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=de_DE.UTF-8       
 [4] LC_COLLATE=en_GB.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=de_DE.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_GB.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=de_DE.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C              
[10] LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=de_DE.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] terra_1.6-17

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.2.1   tools_4.2.1      Rcpp_1.0.9       codetools_0.2-18
```

**Edit:**

Using the function without the namespace results in another error.

```
KMin <- Reduce(min, rlist)
Error: [f] unknown function argument
```

Comment: @bretauv, the functions in the first comment result in single value not a SpatRaster. These functions are documented here,, https://rspatial.github.io/terra/reference/terra-package.html they are part of the package.

Comment: It is a huge data in NetCDF format. The errors are identical to the example errors I posted in my question.

Comment: Take a look at `?terra::app`.

Comment: @Chris, I did test it already. And x (input) should be SpatRaster or SpatRasterDataset not a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the more terra-idiomatic way to do that, with `tapp`

Your example data

```
library(terra)
f <- rast(system.file("ex/elev.tif", package="terra"))
ff <- c(f,f)
rlist <- list(ff, ff, ff)
```

Solution:

```
r <- rast(rlist)
idx <- rep(1:2, length(rlist))
idx
#[1] 1 2 1 2 1 2

Kmean <- tapp(r, idx, mean)
Kmedian <- tapp(r, idx, median)
Ksd <- tapp(r, idx, sd)
KMin <- tapp(r, idx, min)
KMax <- tapp(r, idx, max)
```

Alternatively, you can create a SpatRasterDataset and use `app`

```
s <- sds(rlist)
Kmean <- app(s, mean)
#etc
```

If you want to use `Reduce` you can replace this

```
KMin <- Reduce(min, rlist)
#Error: [f] unknown function argument
```

With

```
KMin <- Reduce(\(i, ...) min(i), rlist)
```

Whereas

```
KMean <- Reduce(mean, rlist)
```

Just works. I suppose that is related to their differences in definitions, with min being a primitive function with ellipses as first argument.

```
min
#function (..., na.rm = FALSE)  .Primitive("min")

mean
#function (x, ...) 
#standardGeneric("mean")
```

---

Finally, it is also possible to get the parallel mean, min, etc. by just doing

```
RMean <- mean(ff, ff, ff)
RMin <- min(ff, ff, ff)
```

And, hence, (with the work-around for `min` and `max`),

```
RMean <- do.call(mean, rlist)
RMin <- do.call(\(i, ...) min, rlist)
```

Comment: thank you very much for the detailed answer! I tested `app` & `tapp` performance and both have similar performance. On another note, many thanks for this great package. It has enormously reduced the computation time for me.